# Clone function not working in c -> pid = clone(&clonefunc, (void*)(stack[i] + (1024*64)), ... NOt working

Tags: c, multithreading, clone, multitasking

I'm trying to make a script that can calculate pi using 4 threads and the function clone, but the function is never actually used properly.

The code does almost everything it's told to, but not what the function is supposed to do, where it assigns `pid = clone(&clonefunc`... I´ve tried everything I can think of.

I really dont know why, this is the code:

**EDIT: i made a couple of changes suggested, but the value of Pi is still not changing for each threads, they end up being the same even when pi is correct (up to 9 digits) in the end

```
    #define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <signal.h>

#define iterations 2000000000
#define NCLONES 4

static double pi[NCLONES];

int clonefunc(void* args){
    int clon_num = *((int *) args);
    printf("clon_num: %d\n",clon_num);
    int i;
    double inicio = clon_num*(iterations/NCLONES);
    double fin = (clon_num +1)*(iterations/NCLONES);

    printf("inicio: %f\tfin: %f",inicio,fin);

    for(i = inicio ; i < fin ; i++){
        if (i % 2)pi[clon_num] -= 1.0/(2*i+1);
        else pi[clon_num] += 1.0/(2*i+1);
    }
    printf("\nPi: %.9lf\n",*pi);
    return 0;
}

int main(){
    int i;
    int clonearray[NCLONES];
    double pi_total = 0;
    pid_t pid;
    long long start_ts;
    long long stop_ts;
    long long elapsed_time;
    struct timeval ts;
    void* stack[NCLONES];

    gettimeofday(&ts, NULL);
    start_ts = ts.tv_sec;

    for(i=0 ; i<NCLONES ; i++){
        printf("se crea el clon %d \n " , i);
        clonearray[i]=i;
        stack[i] = malloc(1024*64);

    pid = clone(&clonefunc, (void*)(stack[i] + (1024*64)), SIGCHLD | CLONE_FS | CLONE_FILES |
                                                                                                CLONE_SIGHAND |  CLONE_VM, &i);
    wait(NULL);

    }       



    for(i=0 ; i<NCLONES ; i++){
        pi_total+=pi[i];
        free(stack[i]);
    }

    gettimeofday(&ts, NULL);
    stop_ts = ts.tv_sec;

    elapsed_time = stop_ts-start_ts;
    printf("----------------------------\n Valor de pi : %.9f \n",(pi_total*4));
    printf("Tiempo total = %d segundos \n ----------------------------\n",(int)elapsed_time);
    return 0;
}
```

Execution shows:

se crea el clon 0 
 clon_num: 0
inicio: 0.000000    fin: 500000000.000000
**Pi: 0.785398163**

se crea el clon 1 
 clon_num: 1
inicio: 500000000.000000    fin: 1000000000.000000
**Pi: 0.785398163**

se crea el clon 2 
 clon_num: 2
inicio: 1000000000.000000   fin: 1500000000.000000
**Pi: 0.785398163**

se crea el clon 3 
 clon_num: 3
inicio: 1500000000.000000   fin: 2000000000.000000
**Pi: 0.785398163**

---

Valor de pi : 3.141592659 
Tiempo total = 16 segundos

---

Comment: Add a `"\n"` to the end of the `clonefunc` call to `printf`. Also, you only have one `wait` but have four child processes. That means the parent will exit as soon as the first child exits instead of waiting for all the children to exit (not sure if that's what yo intended).

Comment: Thanks! it worked on somethings, although its still has a couple of errors as its stills give a wrong answer